# Dragging a window makes it become choppy

Tags: windows-xp

On my old computer when you drag a window around, it seems to be cut up (like what you'd see in remote desktop on a slow connection) and its becoming really annoying.

A few weeks when I was transferring data from it to my new laptop and it was working fine then however when I started it a few minutes ago this issue occurred.

I tried restarting several time with no luck.

> OS: Windows XP Professional
>
> Graphics Card: nVidia 9600GT

Comment: You stated `A few weeks when I was transferring data from it to my new laptop however when I started it a few minutes ago this issue occurred.` You missed the part where you say that it was working fine then or it wasn't.

Comment: oh sorry, fixed that.

Comment: How much has your graphics card been used? It might be dead/dying.

Comment: not much, i rarely played games as it was only for school work

Comment: Alright. Check if the drivers are installed and up to date also check if its plugged in properly.

Comment: yeah the drivers are up to date as i updated them before thinking it was the problem. how do i check if its plugged in properly?

Comment: `I was transferring data from it to my new laptop` perhaps your hard disk is dying

Comment: There should be a 6-pin plug (I think its a 6-pin?) that is connected to the graphics card at the back of it. Make sure its in correctly, and make sure the computer is turned off & unplugged for safety while you do that.

Comment: oh, the plug had came out slightly as the clip is broken. can you post that as a answer? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Video cards require a power source to function correctly, otherwise they have insufficient power to render windows/games and etc.

You should replace the plug to stop it falling out of the socket however as a temporary fix you can use some tape to keep it in in case the computer moves.

Comment: WHAT?!?  There was no mention of a video card physically moving... If ANYTHING, it's an old driver and/or a slower computer.  Choppy redrawing of a window is usually from old slow drivers, no graphics acceleration and loaded cpu(s), or just flat out overloaded system bogging down.  Video cards do NOT 'degrade gracefully on low power'... they fail utterly and you get a blank screen on your monitor.   TAPE IT IN?!?  Which color Duct Tape did you use?

Comment: @lornix It was a long shot. Also because I've had this issue before and it took me several days to work out that the video card had moved and I didn't know. Also, video cards DO work with low power, they just don't work well. Also taping the plug in is a temporary solution to keeping the plug connected to the video card in case it does move. Also, read the comments on the question.